# Ruby, nokogiri and csv: about different sets of data

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing, csv, nokogiri

I have something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

fields = ['Full name', 'Address', 'Valid phone', 'E-mail']
availableFields = []
availableDataFields = []

CSV.open('myfile4.csv', 'a', {:col_sep => ';', :force_quotes => true}) do |csv|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(some_of_my_urls))

    #We are on the right page if we have content in this tag
    if doc.xpath('//div[@class = "pad8"]/h3').length > 0

        availableFields << 'Full name'
        availableFields << doc.xpath('//div[@class = "pad8"]/div[@class = "block pad8"]/table/tr/td[1]').text.gsub(/\n+|\r/, "").strip.split(':')
        #We received and parsed available fields on this page from td[1]
        #availableFields = ['Full name', 'Address', 'E-mail']

        availableDataFields << doc.xpath('//div[@class = "pad8"]/h3').text
        availableDataFields << doc.xpath('//div[@class = "pad8"]/div[@class = "block pad8"]/table/tr/td[3]').text.gsub(/\n+|\r/, "").strip
        #We received and parsed available fields data on this page from another td (td[3])
        #availableDataFields = ['John Doe', 'New York', 'john.doe@mail.com']

    end

    #Write to CSV file
    csv << fields
    csv << availableDataFields

end
```

So when i open CSV file i have this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Full name    |    Address   |         Valid phone       |              E-mail                  |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     John Doe     |   New York   |      john.doe@mail.com    |                                      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

instead of this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Full name    |    Address   |         Valid phone       |               E-mail                 |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     John Doe     |   New York   |                           |          john.doe@mail.com           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because some of my pages (`some_of_my_urls`) might contain not full of available fields but we can parse which of them page has and we definitely know all available fields (`fields`) that page might have.

How can i properly fix this and how can i (possibly) use `availableFields` for it. Maybe compare `fields` and `availableFields` and based on this generate right row of csv data? But how?

EDIT: Here is HTML code: [case 1](http://9503.selcdn.ru/i/case.html), [case 2](http://9503.selcdn.ru/i/case2.html)

Comment: So `availableDataFields` isn't always coming out the same size? Why not just add empty strings in the appropriate places? Perhaps some sample HTML would help.

Comment: You really need to show some html.

Comment: If you use an iterator (`each`), you won't need the if statement, and your XPaths will be shorter. There are likely other improvements that can be made but we'll need to see the HTML.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for reply. i just added the html code examples in question. “Why not just add empty strings in the appropriate places?“ — i have same idea before, but i don't know how to it better. `fields - availableFields` then get position in array and add empty string in `availableDataFields`

Comment: @pguardiario, updated question with code examples

Comment: @MarkThomas thanks for tip. I added html code examples in question.